# Exceptions when try to start MediaPlayer

Tags: android

I try to play some music for my activity but "sometimes" it throws exceptions below :

```
android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
```

This is my code that might be related on this error.

```
...
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    bgm.start();
});
thread.start();
...
```

This code is in `onCreate` method and rest part is just make some animations with `Handler` or get 3 `String` intent values and five `int` intent values from previous activity.
It doesn't even tell me which line of my code it happened.

Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Solutions:**

1. Override your service's `onDestroy()` method and watch what event flow leads to it. If you catch `DeadObjectException` without going through this method, your service should have been killed by the OS.
2. by removing Typeface, this might be because of ttf which I was using from the assets folder Please try comment the typeface and test it hope it will work for sure
3. put all your code inside the `onCreate`. From there you will see what is the culprit like a `NullPointerException` for example but your code will run smoothly already.

> DeadObjectException: The object you are calling has died, because its
> hosting process no longer exists.